# chmod php return invalid value

Tags: php, chmod

I'am trying this code

```
<?php
$file = "/tmp/testfile2.txt";
$source = "text";


// substr(decoct(fileperms($file)), -4) // this is to get current file perms 
// if $file not exist, set default chmod to 0655
$chmod = (is_file($file)?substr(decoct(fileperms($file)), -4):'0655'); 

echo "save chmod variable : $chmod\n";

if(file_put_contents($file, $source)){ //if write success

    echo "now executing chmod : $chmod\n";
    chmod($file,$chmod);

    clearstatcache(); // clear stat cache
    $chmod = substr(decoct(fileperms($file)), -4);
    echo "new chmod variable value : $chmod\n";
}else{
     echo "fail";
}
```

If file not exist, chmod to 0655, but always return invalid chmod value

```
save chmod variable : 0655
now executing chmod : 0655
new chmod variable value : 1217
```

Here live test : https://3v4l.org/jgmeR

Whats wrong ?

Comment: '0655' is not interpreted as an octal number. for inputs you must use intval($mode, 8).

Comment: thanks, solved my problem with `decoct($chmod)`